# Delete messages in a queue on a RabbitMQ (AMQP) server

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq, amqp

I have 1 big task which consists out of 200 sub-tasks (messages) which will be published onto a queue. If I want to cancel this 1 task, the 200 messages (or the ones that are left and not processed yet) should be deleted. Is there any way to delete these published messages in a queue?

One solution I could think of is to create a queue (Q) which where I publish the name of a new queue (X). Each consumer connects then to this new dynamically created queue (X) and process the 200 published messages. If I want to abort the entire task I delete only that queue (X) from the publisher side. Is that a common approach?

Comment: Sounds like a good approach.

Comment: How about a similar approach to DB transaction. Starts with an initial start message push it into the Queue and then insert the remaining messages. If processing goes well insert the final commit message else insert a rollback or discard message.
Ensure that start message, final message and discard/ rollback message are uniquely identified and handled at the other consumer side.

Comment: Although for this kind of requirement. Kafka would have been my first choice as it provides the functionality of transaction in the messaging queue. 
Here you get the functionality of sending sub tasks message to Kafka queue aka. topic they won't be read by other queue consumers until you commit the ongoing transaction. Even you don't have to worry about deleting the messages in an aborted transaction.
See [Kafka Transactional Messaging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Transactional+Messaging+in+Kafka)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few issues with your suggested approach.

The first problem is due to RMQ [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) which is intended to improve performance by reducing the amount of requests to the broker. If your consumers have retrieved a batch of tasks they will process them all before they ask for new ones, only then they will realize the queue was cancelled. Therefore, your cancellation request would not be handled properly most of the times. You could reduce the prefetch count to 1 to avoid this side effect but this would increase the pressure over the network and reduce overall speed.

The second issue is that the AMQP protocol does not provide mechanisms for gracefully dealing with queue deletion. Therefore your consumers would need to carefully deal with queues disappearing as they would otherwise crash. By doing so, you would loose visibility over bugs and issues. How can you distinguish when a queue was explicitly deleted from a case where it actually crashed?

What I would recommend in this case is marking all your tasks with an identifier of their parent job. Each time a consumer starts consuming a new task, it would check if the parent job is valid or has been cancelled. In the latter case, it would simply ignore the task and move to the next one. You need a supporting service for that. A Redis instance should be more then enough for example.

This mechanism would be way simpler and robust. You can spin as many consumers as you want without the need of orchestrating their connection to the right queue. Also out-of-order or interleaved tasks would not be a problem.